# get logged in user in AutoMapper profile

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

I have asp.net core 2.0 web api project.
Every Domain class inherits BaseEntity class:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

for converting view models to DTO-s I use AutoMapper.

I created two profiles, one for ViewModel to DTO and another for DTO to ViewModel.

In the profile where I map ViewModels to DTOs, I need that `BaseEntity` fields

```
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }
```

to be mapped from authorized user. I have already set up authentication, just need to access the authorized user object from AutoMapper profile class.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: See [this](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html) and [this](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use custom value resolvers in AutoMapper to get your user object into the context.

Profile Configuration

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModel, Dto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.CreatedBy, opt => opt.ResolveUsing((src, dest, destMember, res) => res.Context.Options.Items["CreatedBy"]));
```

When Calling Mapper

```
Mapper.Map<ViewModel, Dto>(src, opt => opt.Items["CreatedBy"] = this.createdByUserObject);
```